# Get slug and write content with dashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm having a problem with getting content from pages where the slug is seperated with dashes. for example if i go to `www.example.com/home` it works fine but if i go for example to `www.example.com/about-us` it gets an error `Trying to get property of non-object` wich as the error says is regarding this lines;

```
<h1><?php echo $page->Title; ?></h1>
<?php echo $page->Content; ?>
```

I have a function that get's the slug from the database that looks like this;

```
function getSlug($name = null) {
global $db;
if ($name) {
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE `Title` = ? LIMIT 1');
    $query->execute(array($name));
    return $query->fetchObject();
}
}
```

I also have a function that creates the slug that looks like this;

```
function createSlug($string){
    $string = preg_replace( '/[«»""!?,.!@£$%^&*{};:()]+/', '', $string );
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
    return $slug;
}
```

In my htaccess i have got the rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]`.

to get the content i used the following code;

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    $slug = create_slug($_GET['name']);
    $page = getSlug($slug);
?>
<div class="container">
    <h1><?php echo $page->Title; ?></h1>
    <?php echo $page->Content; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I really don't have any clue what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Check ModRewrite module enabled and also, in .htaccess check the below line is added in top.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @sk8terboi87 , my htaccess looks like this;

     `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      # RewriteBase /

      # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
      RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
 

      </IfModule>

      <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c> 
           ErrorDocument 404 index.php
      </IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding a row in my databse called Slug, i think this will also be better if i want the slug to be different then the title.

Thanks for the efforts @sk8terboi87

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Instead of changing in htaccess, saving the slug in db and simply showing the "sluggified' links. nice!